# Is it possible to cancel a transaction before it's completed?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have an in-app purchase that can be made, but it has to happen within a 60-second window. The user is kicked out of that ViewController once the timer runs out and they don't tap any purchase buttons. However, if they do tap a purchase button and then the time runs out, they are kicked out of the ViewController but can still complete their purchase.

In my situation, they are buying a promotional slot in the app and it is possible that another user wants to buy the same slot at the same time, so whichever user starts the process first, gets a 60-second reservation on that slot which prevents other users from purchasing it in the same time period.

Once the time runs out, the slot becomes available to everyone again. So what could happen is the user could be mid-transaction, the time could run out, and then someone else purchases the slot before the first user finishes their transaction.

I need a way to CANCEL the transaction while it's showing on the screen, before completion.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7I4H.jpg

```swift
let currentQueue : SKPaymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()
for transaction in currentQueue.transactions {
    currentQueue.finishTransaction(transaction) // 
}
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot finish a purchasing transaction'

Comment: No, once you have submitted a purchase request it cannot be cancelled. It sounds like a better approach would be for the purchase a slot entitlement and then to apply that entitlement to a specific slot later

Comment: @Paulw11 Do you think it would be viable to make it so that the purchase goes through no matter what, and if another person has claimed the slot by that point, the first purchaser just gets a voucher of some kind to use later? Would Apple approve of that?